# Why is insertion sort "decrease and conquer" whereas selection sort is "brute force"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Why are insertion sort algorithms also not considered brute force algorithms? Don't they systematically look through every value of the array as well? I undertand that selection sort has a worst best-case time complexity, but I'm still not fully understanding the differentiation between a brute-force algorithm and a decrease-and-conquer algorithm. Sorry if this is a stupid question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't really know where did you get that, but to me both insert sort and select sort are brute force. Both of those algorithms have exactly the same worst case complexity O(N^2). Maybe you're reffering to merge sort, which is most often called 'divide and conquer algorithm'? Some may also call quicksort 'divide and conquer'

Comment: Basically 'divide and conquer' means you're dividing input data into groups and solving your problem only for those parts, then using the results to get the answer for the whole set of data quicker. Insert sort does not use that technique anywhere.

Comment: Tbh I dont understand why people are downvoting, so upvoted. Indeed Recursive Insertion Sort is considered decrease and conquer while the iterative version is considered brute force.  This is because the set you're comparing it to decreases with every recursive call. This is ofcourse the same with iterative insertion sort but someone in uni made this call ;P

Answer (score 0):

Both insertion and selection sort might be called “decrease and conquer” because at every step of outer loop they treat smaller and smaller part of array.

Formally speaking, in these sorts `loop invariant condition is that the subarray A[0 to i-1] is always sorted`.

I have not met “brute force” term in application to sorting algorithms, it looks like nonsense. Brute force algorithms usually check all possible variants and choose the best one. It is possible to generate all permutations of an array or list and choose sorted one - this kind of sortinh might be called "stupid sort" or [something like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).